# Angular get image from api with style background-image

Tags: javascript, css, angular

At this time i get an image from an API and print it to the view with interpolation:

```html
<img src="{{url + '/get-product-image/' + product.image}}" *ngIf="product.image" class="img"/>
```

My question is: It's posible to 'interpolate' from [style.background] or something like this?.

My css:

```css
#banner{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,.8)),
    url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460306855393-0410f61241c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1952&q=80');
}
```

My goal is to interpolate the background-image of a html element:

```html
<section id="banner">
```

I've been trying this but logs errors in console:

```html
<section [style.backgroundImage]="{{url + '/get-product-image/' + product.image}}"></section>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using below :

```
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(' + imgURL + ') no-repeat 0 0 / cover'}" class="flex-center">
</div>
```

Here is the stackBlitz link : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t7gpys?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ur syntax is wrong.
It should work when using "style.backgroundImage" like this:

```
<section [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + URL_OF_IMAGE + ')'"></section>
```